# EU permanent residence application

Tags: residency

I had lived in Germany continuously for 6 years, then moved to the Netherlands and been living here continuously for 2 years now. I would like to apply for the EU permanent residence. I have a professional job, university degree and a good steady income. Where and how do I apply since I no longer live in Germany and have not been in the Netherlands 5 years?

Comment: There is no such thing as ‘EU permanent residence’. You can only apply for permanent residence in a specific country once you’ve fulfilled the residency requirements.

Comment: @Traveller there is EU long-term residence for third-country nationals.  It is indeed based on residence in a particular country, other than the UK, Ireland, or Denmark, but once it is acquired, it can be fairly easily transferred to another EU member state other than those three.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably thinking of [Directive 2003/109/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02003L0109-20110520).  The status does not accrue automatically.  To benefit from this directive you must apply to your country of residence after having lived there for more than five years (see Article 7).  It seems from your question that you did not do that while living in Germany.

> Where and how do I apply since I no longer live in Germany and have not been in the Netherlands 5 years?

From the information given in the question, it seems that your only option is to wait three years and apply to the Dutch IND.